# Understanding the bokeh server

Tags: bokeh

I am unable to find mention of how many sessions the `bokeh-server` is capable of handling.

I would like to include some plots in my web app and would like an idea for how a single bokeh server will handle my traffic of ~ 100 users at any given time. Each users' page may have as many as 10 bokeh plots on the page. I would use `redis` as the backend

My stack is as follows (all on a single core VPS, 1G RAM):

- `nginx` (webserver)
- `uwsgi` (application server)
- `flask` (web framework)
- `redis` (in-memory data persistence)

How does the `bokeh-server` configuration option `--multi-user` play into my use case? I am having trouble understanding the scope of the bokeh `session`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: The question above, and the answer below are regarding the old, long-gone first generation Bokeh server, before Bokeh `0.11`. For information about using the current Bokeh server, which is more stable, performant, as well as simpler to use and better documented, see:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

a few thoughts:

regarding load - unknown, but it's not so much about number of users, but how large your data is, as most of the overhead is json serialization/deserialization. One user could swamp the bokeh server if the json content is gigantic.  But under normal usage I would expect 100 users to be no problem

Note, If you only using one core, I don't nginx isn't going to help much.

regaring multi user -- it means different users can register with their own username and password.  This means that users won't stomp on each others documents.  In the single user case, the bokeh session always connects to the bokeh server as the user "defaultuser"  in the multiuser case users must register, and login to the session using their credentials. "multi user" is more important when users are *publishing* content, since (IIUC) you are at the only one pushing content to the server, it should not be an issue.